# Reference request for the proof of the Brodskii–Milman fixed point theroem for isometries

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Can any one help me to access the paper

> M.S Brodskii and D.P Milman, On the center of a convex set, *Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR* **59** (1948) 837–840 in Russian?

or to prove the theorem

> If $K$ is a weakly compact, bounded convex subset of a Banach space with normal structure, then there exists $x_0\in K$ such that $T(x_0)=x_0$ for all surjective isometry $T:K\to K$. That is there is a common fixed point for the family of surjective isometris on $K$.

Thank you.

Comment: What does "normal structure" mean?